# How to fade in and out an ActivityIndicator in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my activity indicator:

```
self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)
self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
```

I can start it with `self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()` and stop it with `self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()`. I'd like the transition when it stops to be more fluid and think it would nice to fade out the element over 400 milliseconds rather than just hiding it when I call stopAnimating.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // Set initial state
    self.activityIndicator.alpha = 0.0

    // To show
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
        self.activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0
    }

    // To hide
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
        self.activityIndicator.alpha = 0.0
    }) { complete in
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An activity indicator is a UIView object. As such you can use UIView animations on it. How about this:

```
func stopActivityIndiator()
{
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: 
  {
    self.activityIndicator.alpha = 0;
  }
  completion:
  {
    (completed) -> () in
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    self.activityIndicator.hidden = true
    self.activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0
  }
  )
}
```

Assuming you have an instance variable activityIndicator that code should fade it away over .4 seconds, then stop it and hide it (so it's ready for next time.)